# Why is my Mailchimp Welcome automation sending only one email and deleting subscriber data?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I have an automation workflow set up with two emails and a landing page, with a Welcome trigger. The first email links to the landing page. The landing page contains a form that has to be completed, verifying the email address. The second email is supposed to be sent after the form is completed.

The problem is the second email isn't sending. I can see that completing the form is deleting all Mailchimp group data related to the subscriber. This means that the second email doesn't send, as I'm segmenting by group membership.

Removing the segmentation should get the second email to send. Will that cause an issue with other list subscribers potentially getting the second email in the workflow?

And, why is the form removing group membership info, rather than updating the record? The initial sign-up is not with a Mailchimp form, but with another solution (RSForm!Pro for Joomla) that is syncing with Mailchimp. Could that be causing the problem?